# How to make more master nodes on kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I got cluster seems like:

[masters]

master

[workers]

worker1
worker2
worker3

I know, that I can add this nodes to inventory and make reinit my cluster.

But mb can I do that without reconfigure inventory file?

I thought that I could do it through `kubectl join --token etc`,

but my output by `kubectl token list` is empty

Comment: No, I dont use okd

Comment: Could you add a link to the ansible role you are using?

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/highly-available-master/):

> You can replicate Kubernetes masters in `kube-up` or `kube-down`
>   scripts for Google Compute Engine. This document describes how to use
>   kube-up/down scripts to manage highly available (HA) masters and how
>   HA masters are implemented for use with GCE.

Also if you want to setup an HA kubernetes cluster on Bare Metal you should check out this [guide](https://github.com/salmanb/Kubernetes-HA-on-baremetal).

If you need to get a better understanding of how HA clusters work overall you should read [this article](https://thenewstack.io/kubernetes-high-availability-no-single-point-of-failure/).

Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: Yes, I deployed cluster on Bare Matel. But this guide also suggests init an existing cluster rather than adding more masters nodes

Comment: In that case, there is an official but more complicated way. Check out this [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/high-availability/)

Comment: Your documentation link talks about creating a cluster and initializing. I have a cluster, the task is to add the master nodes